# How to convert column values from string to decimal?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a dataframe which contains a really big integer value, example:

```
42306810747081022358
```

When I've tried to convert it to long it was working in the Java but not under the spark envrironment, I was getting

```
   NumberFormatException: For input string("42306810747081022358")
```

Then I tried to convert it too Decimal (BigDecimal) value. Again, easily can do it in Java, but in Spark: 
     dframe.withColumn("c_number",col("c_a").cast(new DecimalType()));

This way I don't get any exceptions, however I can see that all result values are null.

I also tried to use UDF for this purpose but get the same results:

```
UDF1 cTransformer = new UDF1<String, BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal call(String aString) throws Exception {
            return new BigDecimal(aString);
        }
    };
sqlContext.udf().register("cTransformer", cTransformer, new DecimalType());
dframe = dframe.withColumn("c_number", callUDF("cTransformer", dframe.col("c_a")));
```

And here again all I'm getting is a column with all zeroes.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
dframe.withColumn("c_number", dframe.col("c_a").cast("decimal(38,0)"))
```

Answer (score 9):

A [Decimal](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html) has a *precision* and *scale* value, by default the precision is 10 and scale is 0.
The precision is the maximum number of digit in your number. In your case you have more than 10 digits so the number can't be cast to a 10 digits Decimal and you have null values.

To avoid that you need to specify a precision large enough to represent your numbers :

```
dframe.withColumn("c_number", dframe.col("c_a").cast(new DecimalType(38,0)))
```

Note that the precision can be up to 38

Answer (score 1):

In scala-spark you can use the DecimalType for conversion:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType
val convertedDf = dframe.withColumn("c_number",trim(col("c_a")).cast(DecimalType(20,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is after you have data in data frame with column that needs to be converted is ready
Try:
**dframe.select($"column_name".cast("decimal(9,2)"))**

Answer (score 0):

In scala :

```
df=df.withColumn("col", $"col".cast(DecimalType(9,2)))
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please elaborate on your code and explain why and how this solves the question.